# Mandar datos a la clase NotificationService.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

Tengo una app que notifica al usuario a través de una alarma unas notificaciones. Y ando intentando averiguar como puedo personalizar el titulo y el mensaje de la notificación, en función de la notificación que se mande. Pero me encuentro el problema en que solo me deja coger la información del archivo Strings.xml, y por lo que leo en internet, no es bueno ni se puede modificar el valor de un string. Mi necesidad es, que quiero mandar desde el fragment que hace un setAlarm, y pasa a la clase AlarmReceiver para luego pasar a la clase NotificationService...los datos del elemento añadido a la BBDD y con el que creo la alarma. De todo lo que he leído en internet, el SharedPreferences es lo más viable que veo...pero en el valor por defecto (que supuestamente hay que dejarlo en blanco) que se pone en el destino para recuperar el valor enviado, no me recoge el valor enviado la variable, por lo que no me muestra los datos enviados en el mensaje de la notificación. Os pongo el código de mis clases:
FragmentEnviar
Utils.setAlarm(consultaIdToma(idMedicamento,horas.get(position).getHora()), calendar.getTimeInMillis(), getContext());

Utils.java

```
void setAlarm(int i, Long timestamp, Context ctx) { 
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class); 
    PendingIntent pendingIntent; pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, i, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
    alarmIntent.setData((Uri.parse("custom://" + System.currentTimeMillis()))); 

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timestamp,1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent); 
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { Intent service1 = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class); 
    service1.setData((Uri.parse("custom://" + System.currentTimeMillis()))); 
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, service1); Log.d("WALKIRIA", " ALARM RECEIVED!!!"); 
}
```

NotificationService.java

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent2) { 
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name); 
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext(); 
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
    Resources res = this.getResources(); 
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM); 
    String message = getString(R.string.new_notification);
}
```

### Como ven, en el String message, de ésta última clase necesito enviar desde mi Fragment el valor de la alarma que creo, para que se muestre en funcion de la alarma, su información correspondiente. No se como desarrollar esta parte. Si saben alguna forma en que pueda realizarlo, se lo agradeceria. Espero que me podáis ayudar..Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te invitamos a leer [ask] y editar tu pregunta por favor, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes que jugar con el método `putExtra()` de la clase `Intent`, justo como mismo pasas información de una actividad a otra lo puedes hacer aquí. Por ejemplo:
Primero debes cambiar el método `setAlarm()` de la calse `Utils` para que acepte un parámetro más, este nuevo parámetro será el mensaje de tu alarma.

```
void setAlarm (int i, long timestamp, Context ctx, String message){
    ...
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent (ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra ("message", message);
    ...
}
```

Luego, en el método `onReceive()` de la clase `AlarmReceiver` solo debes tomar el valor y pasarlo a la clase `NotificationService`

```
@Override public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent){
    ...
    Intent service1 = new Intent (context, NotificationService.class);
    service1.putString("message", intent.getStringExtra("message"));
    ...
}
```

Ahora en el método `onHandleIntent()` de la clase `NotificationService` recuperas ese valor

```
protected void onHandelIntent (Intent intent2){
    ...
    String message = intent2.getStringExtra("message");
    ...
}
```

Y ya en la clase `FragmentEnviar` puedes "llamar" la alarma y pasarle el mensaje que desees
FragmentEnviar

```
Utils.setAlarm(consultaIdToma(idMedicamento, horas.get(position),getHora()), calendar.getTimeInMillis(), getContext(), "Hora de la aspirina");
```

Comment: Ya lo he probado lo que me dijiste Ariel, y en la clase AlarmReceiver no me deja meter el método .putString en el intent...

Comment: Conseguido! Mas o menos fue como me comentaste. GRACIAS

Comment: Que bueno compañero